# Symfony deploy google cloud

Tags: symfony, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, lexikjwtauthbundle

I am deploying symfony app to google cloud, I did this (https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-symfony-on-appengine-standard) tutorial followed and everythings is ok.

I am using LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle for authentication but I cannot generate ssh keys.

How I can run this commands on google cloud

```
openssl genpkey -out config/jwt/private.pem -aes256 -algorithm rsa -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:4096
openssl pkey -in config/jwt/private.pem -out config/jwt/public.pem -pubout
```

Comment: I assume you have to generate your key pair upfront and upload it together with your application code into Google cloud.

Answer (score 2):

You can't run those commands on the AppEngine, you need to run them before deployment and deploy the keys.

The filesystem is readonly which means that you cannot create any files (ouside of /tmp) which in turn means there is no other way than to generate the keys on the system you're deploying from (e.g. your computer).